# Is PDF file optimization available in Python matplotlib as is available in R?

Tags: python, r, pdf, matplotlib

I recently created a large dot plot PDF file using Python and matplotlib. The plot contains 20,000 dots.  The display of the PDF in Acrobat Reader was slow.

I showed the file to a colleague. He said R optimizes the output of PDF files.

Does matplotlib have optimization settings for file output? or is there another visualization Python library that would offer this feature?

This question is a similar to this question. [Matplotlib PDF backend slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103724/matplotlib-pdf-backend-slow)

Any known updates beyond what is mentioned in the related question?

[Edit]

Below is the Python code, as requested, that generates a plot as part of the Collatz Conjecture. This plot is similar to the first one shown on this Wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

I am just learning Python and have not written in the 'spirit' of Python. That's for later. The last three lines produce the PDF file in question.

```
maxnumber = 20000
def collatz(n,nlist):
    nlist.append(n)
    if n != 1 :
        if(n%2 == 1):
            collatz(n*3 + 1, nlist)
        else:
            collatz(int(n/2), nlist)
    return

collatzlist = []
for n in range(2,maxnumber+1): #[n,m) 
    nlist = []
    collatz(n, nlist)
    collatzlist.append(nlist)
collatzycount = []
collatzxcount = []
count = 1
for x in collatzlist:
    collatzxcount.append(count)
    collatzycount.append(len(x))
    count = count + 1

collatzhistoy = [0] * (max(collatzycount)+1)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure('collatz iteration plot')
plt.plot(collatzxcount,collatzycount, "ro")
fig.savefig('collatziteration.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Well... what exactly is within the R-generated pdf? It it rasterized? You can always rasterize a plot (in matplotlib too) which makes rendering fast, but you lose the general advantages of vector-graphics. But sometimes, with huge plots, it's just needed. And for further debugging: why not show the code? Maybe there are other problems. I did a lot of garbage within ipython-notebooks in the past, so that past plot-layers were written to the output-SVG too (while beeing invisible / not distinguishable)

Comment: I would say that a `scatter` plot with 20'000 dots isn't very useful. If you are interested in showing e.g. clusters of points, you could look into something like `hexbin` (http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html)

Comment: I've never heard of R "optimizing" a PDF file like this. I mean, in a `knitr` document you could specify a `png` as the graphic device for an invidual plot, rasterizing it, but still include it in a bigger PDF output. But it's not automatic...